Why PyCharmIDE and Jupyter Notebook Has Discrepancy in Output
I hope you're doing well.
I am currently working in PyCharm Community Edition 2024.2.1(with Python 3.12) IDE and using Pandas version 2.2.3 as the API to manage a dataframe stored in an Excel file. However, I am encountering an issue in PyCharm that does not occur when running the same code in Jupyter Notebook (Jupyter lab 4.2.5).
Here's the scenario:
In Excel File
Project:                                                    
Panel Name:             Mounting Location:                                  
Location:               Mounting Type:                                  
Feed From:              Feed Type:                                  
                                                    
Ckt. No.    LOAD DESCRIPTION    VOLTAGE (V) CL  DL  Phase(A)        PROTECTION                      
            cl(kVA) dl(kVA) L-L 3Ø  AT  AF  kAIC    P           
1   area1   230 0.12    0.12                                    
2   area2   230 0.09    0.09                                    
3   area3   230 0.36    0.18                                    
4   area4   230 1.50    0.75                                    
5   area5   230 0.72    0.36                                    
6   SPARE   230                                         
7   SPARE   230                                         
8   SPARE   230 

For my Jupyter notebook point of view

For my PyCharm Community Edition

As shown in the image, there seems to be a discrepancy when reading the dataframe, particularly in PyCharm. If I were to automate the calculations, this difference could lead to errors, especially when slicing or accessing specific columns and rows.
For example, in Jupyter, I can execute the following without any issues:
S1D['L-L'] = (S1D['cl(kVA)'] / 0.23).round(decimal=2)

This works perfectly in Jupyter. However, in PyCharm, I encounter columns labeled 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', etc., which causes errors when trying to use the same slicing/Series approach.
My question is: why does PyCharm behave differently in this context? My goal is to use Python’s OOP capabilities along with Pandas and have everything work seamlessly in PyCharm, so I can simply run the code by typing python main.py.
Hopefully, someone can guide me or explain what I need to do to resolve this issue.
detail explanation what when wrong between two IDE.

I can see the same "unnamed" columns in both outputs. What you see in Jupyter are the index level names (since you are using the index_col parameter). Try loading without that parameter. In any case, of you print S1D.index.names you'll see these names in PyCharm.
